# Narrowing conversion in C++

Tags: c++, standards, narrowing

In [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#serialization), there is a function that was meant to provide a portable way to serialize a 16-bit integer.

```
/*
** packi16() -- store a 16-bit int into a char buffer (like htons())
*/ 
void packi16(unsigned char *buf, unsigned int i)
{
    *buf++ = i>>8; *buf++ = i;
}
```

I don't understand why the statement `*buf++ = i;` is portable, as the assignment of an unsigned integer (`i`) to an unsigned character (`*buf`) would result in a narrowing conversion.

- Does the C++ standard guarantees that in such a conversion, the `unsigned int` is always truncated and its least significant 8 bits are retained in the `unsigned char`?
- If not, is there any preferred way to fix the issue? Is it adequate to change the function body to the following?

  *buf++ = (i>>8) & 0xFFFFU; *buf++ = i & 0xFFFFU;

Comment: Do note that `unsigned int` is rarely ever 16 bits now. Other than that, the assignment would use a number that fits in the destination type and is congruent modulo 2ⁿ, where n is the number of bits in the destination type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code assumes an 8-bit byte, and that is not portable.

E.g. some Texas Instruments digital signal processors have 16-bit byte.

The number of bits per byte is given by `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>`.

Also, the code assumes that `unsigned` is 16 bits, which is not portable.

In summary the code is not portable.

---

Re

> *”* Does the C++ standard guarantees that in such a conversion, the unsigned int is always truncated and its least significant 8 bits are retained in the unsigned char?

No, since the C++ standard does not guarantee that the number of bits per byte is 8.

The only guarantee is that it's *at least* 8 bits.

Unsigned arithmetic is guaranteed modular, however.

---

Re

> ” If not, is there any preferred way to fix the issue?

Use a simple loop, iterating `sizeof(unsigned)` times.

The code in question appears to have been distilled from such a loop, since the post-increment in `*buf++ = i;` is totally meaningless (this is the last use of `buf`).

Comment: If the system does not have 8-bit bytes then it's unclear whether the intention is to divide the input into octets, or divide it into bytes. IMHO in this instance "portable" should be taken to mean "portable to other situations with 8-bit bytes".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask a follow-up question? If `CHAR_BIT>8` and I read/write an `unsigned char` from/to a binary file , would all `CHAR_BIT` bits of x and y be read/written, or just 8 bits (and which 8 bits)?

Comment: @user740006: Depends on the code and file abstraction. With C++ standard streams `f.write( p, 1 )` writes exactly 1 byte of whatever `p` points at when `f` is in binary mode. That is, the C++ unit of memory is a byte, with `sizeof(char)` = 1 *by definition*, no matter how many bits a byte is. But if `p` points to an `unsigned`, say, then the effect depends on the machine architecture. On a little-endian machine such as a Windows PC it will write the least significant byte of the pointee. On a big-endian machine it will write the most significant byte. To avoid this one can convert to text.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I think one can say that it's portable between compilers with 8-bit byte and 16-bit `unsigned`. The portability is then with respect to endianness, namely, that the byte array is guaranteed filled with a big-endian representation of the value. But this is what the `htons` (winsock, "host byte order to network byte order short") function is for.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't understand. Endianness aside, how can an ASCII text file be transferred safely if the character width on one platform is unknown to another? A computer with `CHAR_BIT=10` will may write the four-character string "ABCD" as `0001000001 0001000010 0001000011 0001000011`, but a computer with `CHAR_BIT=8` may read 8 bits in each turn and end up with five characters `00010000 01000100 00100001 00001100 01000011`, i.e. "[data link escape]D![NP form feed, new page]C". What am I missing? (I come from other fields than CS. Please excuse my silly questions.)

Comment: @user740006: You're just missing that network protocols specify the exact sizes of the data units used in transmission. Each side converts to/from that. This is much of the reason why in telecommunications one talks about "octets", not "bytes".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, out-of-range assignments to unsigned types adjust the value modulo one greater than the maximum value representable in the type. In this case, mod `UCHAR_MAX+1`.

No fix is required. Some people like to write `*buf++ = i % 0x100;` or equivalent, to make it clear that this was intentional narrowing.